# invalid apply tactic, failed to unify

Tags: lean

I'm just learning Lean, currently on [Advanced Addition world, level 5/13](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/natural_number_game/?world=8&level=5).

I have a hypothesis `h` that `succ (a + d) = succ (b + d)`. I also have a `succ_inj` theorem that says `succ(a) = succ(b) → a = b`. I can't figure out how to get `a + d = b + d` from it. If I try to `apply succ_inj h`, it fails with:

```
invalid apply tactic, failed to unify
  a = b
with
  a + d = b + d
state:
case mynat.succ
a b d : mynat,
hd : a + d = b + d → a = b,
h : succ (a + d) = succ (b + d)
⊢ a = b
```

I was thinking I could introduce `x = a + d` and `y = b + d`, rewrite `h` to get `succ(x) = succ(y)`, apply `succ_inj` on that, then rewrite `x = y` back to `a + d = b + d`. But I can't figure out how to introduce `x = a + d` as a hypothesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `apply` tactic only does *one thing* and that is to *change the goal* from Q to P, given the hypothesis that P implies Q. You do not want to change the goal, you want to introduce a new hypothesis. Try `have h2 := succ_inj h`?

You might alternatively want to think hard about what the `apply` tactic does (as opposed to what the English word "apply" means, which is a completely different question) and see if you can use the `apply` tactic to continue.

Over the last few years I have noticed again and again that people find it really hard to understand what the `apply` tactic does and I conjecture that this is because mathematicians informally use the word "apply" to mean lots of different things.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much! Makes sense now! `have h2 := succ_inj h, exact hd(h2),` worked. Also `apply hd, apply succ_inj, exact h,`. I actually had the right idea about `apply` until I asked ChatGPT about it. (https://i.imgur.com/drPZGip.png) I thought I could avoid bothering anyone with my beginner questions...

Comment: If that worked, `exact hd (succ_inj h)` also should.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard: do you have a beetter suggestion on what to call `apply`? I think some time ago it was popular to call the proof technique "backchaining" – but that's even worse as far as mathematicians are concerned.

Comment: `reduce`? I had just assumed that it had been `apply` for decades in the CS community and naming was no longer up for debate. I particularly like `reduce` because computer scientists use it to mean something totally different, so it's like we're getting our revenge.